In Symfony 7 app Monolog is not logging in prod.log
As the tittle says, my Symfony 7 application uses monolog for logging, but is not working at prod level, just at debug level. "prod.log" remains empty even when I force errors or I use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface library.
In .env, enviroment is set as APP_ENV=prod
This is my monolog.yaml file:
monolog:
    channels:
        - deprecation # Deprecations are logged in the dedicated "deprecation" channel when it exists

when@dev:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ["!event"]
            # uncomment to get logging in your browser
            # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
            #firephp:
            #    type: firephp
            #    level: info
            #chromephp:
            #    type: chromephp
            #    level: info
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]

when@test:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                channels: ["!event"]
            nested:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug

when@prod:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: debug
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
            nested:
                type: stream
                # path: php://stderr
                path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
                level: debug
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
            deprecation:
                type: stream
                channels: [deprecation]
                # path: php://stderr
                path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json


This is my composer.json file:
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "*",
        "doctrine/orm": "*",
        "symfony/console": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.10",
        "symfony/runtime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "7.0.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "7.0.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/stopwatch": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "7.0.*"
    }
}


My bundles.php file
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];


I've tried different configurations at the monolog.yaml file:

Swapping action_level from info to debug
Swapping fingers_crossed configuration to stream.
Replacing php://stderr path for %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'

Thank you very much!

Just in case, look for additional monolog.yaml files in other locations.

Thanks for the tip! But it appears that's the only monolog.yaml file in my project.

I can't spot anything wrong in your setup. The only idea that comes to my mind is that prod mode caches things heavily. If you've been trying different configurations in monolog.yaml, they won't take effect unless you clear cache.

Have you made sure that your web server user has write permissions to the var/log/ directory in your production environment? Check out the Symfony docs on Setting up or Fixing File Permissions if you suspect that might be the problem.
